# Strange struct declaration

Tags: c, arrays, struct, constants, lookup

I am familiar with structs and arrays in C, however I have no idea what is going on in the below code. The order for struct declaration is usually:

```
struct employee {
  char title;
  int year;
} mark;
```

Why are there 2 words after struct (below) as well as the [] bracket? As far as I know it is used as condition, action lookup table.

```
const struct act_tbl ActionTbl[] =
{
    {0, BUZZ | DISP | A_ONCE},
    {0, BUZZ | DISP | A_ONCE},
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The first part of your code,

```
struct employee {
  char title;
  int year;
} mark;
```

means "Define a struct called employee, then create an instance of it called `mark`."  It's equivalent to the more verbose

```
struct employee {
  char title;
  int year;
};
struct employee mark;
```

The second part of your code,

```
const struct act_tbl ActionTbl[]={    {0, BUZZ|  DISP|  A_ONCE},
                                          {0, BUZZ|  DISP|  A_ONCE},
```

};

Means "create an array of objects of type `struct act_tbl` where the first `act_tbl` is initialized to `{0, BUZZ|  DISP|  A_ONCE}` and the second is initialized to `{0, BUZZ|  DISP|  A_ONCE}` as well."  Without more knowledge about what `act_tbl` is, though, I don't think I can offer any more advice about why it's written the way it is.

Comment: @arch: Which means that struct act_tbl is defined somewhere else in your code. Probably in a header file somehwere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It is defined in another file as:
 
struct act_tbl
{
 uint32 U32_Condition; 
 uint32 U32_Action; 
};

//There are more entries such as {0,        BRK|         DISP},
     {0,        KEEP|       DISP|},    

//Any idea how it would be used? Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

It seems that:

```
struct act_tbl
```

Refers to a (struct) type that has been declared named act_tbl.

```
const struct act_tbl ActionTbl[]
```

Is initialising a 'const' form of that struct named ActionTbl[] (with the [] indicating the creation of an array)

```
{ {0, BUZZ| DISP| A_ONCE}, {0, BUZZ| DISP| A_ONCE}, };
```

Are the initialising parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`struct act_tbl` is the type, and `ActionTbl` is the variable it declares.

A `[]` after the variable says that it is an array.  Since it lacks an integer in between, the size of the array is determined by the number of initializers.

Answer (score 0):

They're defining and initializing an array of act_tbl structures.